# Maven Build Issue with AlgoTrader 2.2.2

Tags: maven, plugins

I'm getting build errors in AlgoTrader 2.2.2 on my Mac.

E.g.

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project algotrader-mda: Could not resolve dependencies for project algotrader:algotrader-mda:pom:2.2.2: The following artifacts could not be resolved: algotrader:algotrader-uml:jar:2.2.2, org.andromda.cartridges:andromda-hibernate-cartridge:jar:3.4-at2, org.andromda.cartridges:andromda-java-cartridge:jar:3.4-at, org.andromda.cartridges:andromda-spring-cartridge:jar:3.4-at7: Failure to find algotrader:algotrader-uml:jar:2.2.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

E

```
WARNING] The POM for algotrader:algotrader-uml:jar:2.2.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.andromda.cartridges:andromda-hibernate-cartridge:jar:3.4-at2 is missing, no dependency information available
```

I'm running Mac OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite,

Java 1.7.0_71

Maven 3.2.3

I've edited ~/.m2/settings.xml to access the AlgoTrader Nexus repository:
settings.xml:

```
<profile>
      <id>algotrader</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>algotraderrepo</id>
          <url>https://repo.algotrader.ch/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>algotraderrepo</id>
          <url>https://repo.algotrader.ch/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>sonatype</id>
        <name>Sonatype Repository</name>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
       <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
       </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
```

1. The files are in the Nexus archive,
2. Some of the files are getting downloaded and installed into the local repository:

dave@vishnu.local:~/.m2/repository$ ls -lR algotrader/algotrader-uml/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 dave  staff  136 Dec 15 15:28 2.2.2

algotrader/algotrader-uml//2.2.2:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 dave  staff  244 Dec 15 15:28 algotrader-uml-2.2.2.jar.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 dave  staff  244 Dec 15 15:28 algotrader-uml-2.2.2.pom.lastUpdated

dave@vishnu.local:~/.m2/repository$ ls -lR org/andromda/cartridges/andromda-hibernate-cartridge/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 dave  staff  136 Dec 15 15:28 3.4-at2

org/andromda/cartridges/andromda-hibernate-cartridge//3.4-at2:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 dave  staff  244 Dec 15 15:28 andromda-hibernate-cartridge-3.4-at2.jar.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 dave  staff  244 Dec 15 15:28 andromda-hibernate-cartridge-3.4-at2.pom.lastUpdated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and how do you activate that build profile ?

Comment: The contents of the .jar file algotrader-uml-2.2.2.jar.lastUpdated:

#NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Mon Dec 15 15:28:19 MST 2014
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1418682499177
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=  Doesn't this mean Maven is trying to download the POMs from the central repository and not Algotrader's repository?

Comment: try adding `<repositories>` (the same one) to your pom.xml instead

Comment: Which XML tag in pom.xml should I add <repositories>?

Comment: Adding <repositories> to pom.xml worked.  Why?  Why does ~/.m2/settings.xml choose the default central repository (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) instead of using <url>https://repo.algotrader.ch/nexus/content/groups/public</url>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `<repositories>` tag to `pom.xml` you are configuring it on `settings.xml` for a `profile` which you are not building against

Comment: Can you elaborate -or- point me to the section in the Maven document which explains this?  Thanks!!

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html also feel free to [mark the answer as accepted since it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)